# Need Help adding values of radio buttons and textboxes

Tags: java, android

I have created an app in Android studio that uses radio buttons grouped in radio button groups and checkboxes, each of which is assigned a value, which is stored when a  specific radio button or checkbox is clicked. Currently there is a calculate button which when clicked calls a submitOrder() method and totals the sum of all the selected radio buttons and checkboxes and displays it on the screen with a message. That works just fine. I want to eliminate the calculate button completely and have the sum autocalculated and refreshed in real time when the user clicks any radio button or combination of radio buttons and checkboxes. I have searched far and wide on Stack Overflow and Google and have not found any useful examples or recommendations on how to call the submitOrder() method in the java code itself. I have tried all kinds of iterations, but no success. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried adding the submitOrder() method in the code associated with each radio button or checkbox, but no success

// the following code is required in order for the radio groups to function without causing an error

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();


}

public void submitOrder(View view) {
```

radio button group variables 
*/

```
    RadioButton radio_one = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_one);
    boolean hasRadioOne = radio_one.isChecked();


    RadioButton radio_two = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_two);
    boolean hasRadioTwo = radio_two.isChecked();

    RadioButton radio_three = (RadioButton)  findViewById(R.id.radio_three);
    boolean hasRadioThree = radio_three.isChecked();

    RadioButton radio_four = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_four);
    boolean hasRadioFour = radio_four.isChecked();


    RadioButton radio_five = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_five);
    boolean hasRadioFive = radio_five.isChecked();



      // this is the starting value for assigning  the  score

    int basePrice = 0;

 // 5 values
    if (addRadioOne) {
        basePrice = basePrice + 3;





    } else if (addRadioTwo) {
        basePrice = basePrice + 1;



    } else if (addRadioThree) {
        basePrice = basePrice + 0;




    } else if (addRadioFour) basePrice = basePrice + 2;


    else if (addRadioFive) basePrice = basePrice + 3;
```

This calculates the total:

```
  private int calculatePrice(boolean addRadioOne, boolean addRadioTwo,                    boolean addRadioThree,boolean addRadioFour, boolean addRadioFive)
```

Comment: The submitOrder(0 method call this: private int calculatePrice(boolean addRadioOne, boolean addRadioTwo, boolean addRadioThree,
                               boolean addRadioFour, boolean addRadioFive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 //So after many attempts and much testing I found that all I had to do was add
 the submitOrder(view:null); in the onRadioButtonClicked method

// the following code is required in order for the radio groups to function 
//without causing an error

public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
// Is the button now checked?
boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
submitOrder(null);
}                

And for the checkboxes similarly we add the submitOrder(view:null); in 
the onCheckBoxClicked method which is called when the CheckBox is clicked

public void onCheckBoxClicked(View view) {
// Is the Checkbox now checked?
boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
submitOrder(null);
}
```

You must have two separate methods, one for RadioButtons and One for
   CheckBoxes which must be called in each radioButton and CheckBox XML code 
   for each object. Otherwise the App will crash.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something as follow:

- You do not have to pass every **RadioButton** or **CheckBox** in `submitOrder()` method.
- You can define common listener using **OnCheckedChangeListener** for each `RadioGroup` or `CheckBox`, Call `submitOrder` in that.
- You can get all values one by one for each `RadioButton` and `CheckBox` either **true or false**

Hope you will convert my words to programming.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the insight !

Comment: RadioGroup respiratory = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.respiratory);
        {
            RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener submitOrder;
        }   // I tried this but to no avail. I am a newer developer so please accept my apologies for my grasshopper skills. As you can see I created an ID for the first radio group, then added the OnCheckedChangeListener for the RadioGroup then called the SubmitOrder.   Is this what you had in mind ? Curious What am I missing ?

Comment: So what I am attempting to do is to have the app autoupdate the grand total when any radio button in any radio group is selected or if a checkbox is checked. I think the problem is that I am attempting to call submitOrder() while I am already in the submitOrder() method. Is that even possible ? I continue on my quest.........

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like below. Set checkedChangeListeners for all the radio buttons. The when each of the radio button is checked/unchecked the listeners will update the sum accordingly.

```
        radio1 = findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        radio2 = findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        radio3 = findViewById(R.id.radio3);
        private int count=0;


        radio1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked)
                    count=count+3;
                else{
                    if(count>0){
                        count=count-3;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(count);
            }
        });

        radio2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked)
                    count++;
                else{
                    if(count>0){
                        count--;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(count);
            }
        });

        radio3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked)
                    count=count+0;
                else{
                    if(count>0){
                        count=count-0;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(count);
            }
        });
```